# Ical feed validation error

Tags: ruby, icalendar

I've implemented an ical feed for my site using the icalendar gem.

feed: http://cosi105b-f2015.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/content/lectures/schedule.ical

validator: http://severinghaus.org/projects/icv/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fcosi105b-f2015.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com%2Fcontent%2Flectures%2Fschedule.ical

And yet when I try to add it to google calendar it does not respect the time zones that I have indicated.

Any theory?

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the TZID parameter on each DTSTART/DTEND. As a consequence, you are generating events in floating time, instead of relative time with TZ.

You should use the following syntax:

```
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20150828T110000
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20150828T122000
```